# SQL what the difference between UPDATE my_table SET status = 'inactive'; and UPDATE my_table SET status = 'inactive' WHERE TRUE;

Tags: sql

know the difference between using WHERE TRUE and not in UPDATE commmand

I would like to know the difference

Comment: None in practice. The second one is longer than the first one.

Comment: You often see WHERE TRUE (or WHERE 1=1) when SQL is being constructed dynamically/programmatically. If your base SQL statement ends with this WHERE clause then you can add additionally filter conditions easily - without worrying if the the condition being added is the first one and therefore you also need to add the WHERE keyword

Comment: SQL what the difference between                                                                           
  UPDATE my_table SET status = 'inactive';                               and                                                
  UPDATE my_table SET status = 'inactive' WHERE TRUE;

Comment: Why have you repeated your question in a comment?

Comment: I've tried to make it clear this why i rewrite the question

Answer (score 0):

If your [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms) supports it ([oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), notably, does not) there's effectively no difference - both statements will update all the rows in the table.

These kind of statements sometimes get generated by automatic code generators that can't just skip the `where` clause, but it's redundant.